# Cloud Run request timeout reverts back to 60 after every update

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-scheduler

I have a Cloud Scheduler job that runs each day and takes around 12 minutes to complete.  I updated the timeout limit to 30 minutes for both the job and the Cloud Run container.  Whenever I update the script of the job, the Cloud Run container's timeout drops back down to 60 seconds.  I change the timeout via Cloud Shell and run:

```
gcloud beta run services update dailyupdates --timeout=1800s
```

Is there a way to make prevent the timeout setting from defaulting back?

Comment: Show the commands that you are using to update your script.

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
gcloud beta run services update dailyupdates --timeout=1800s --update-env-vars=MY_TIMEOUT=1800s
```

EDIT
for reference you may want to go through [update](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/run/services/update)

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: i understand that but i was waiting for the clarification that whether this solves the issue or not . anyway it is in edit now.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to work.  It creates a new environment variable that remains 1800s even after an update, but the Request timeout value still drops back to 60s.

Comment: @Rainysidewalks do I need to associate the default with the new environment variable somehow?  Or is there a way to check what the name of the current variable is, if its not MY_TIMEOUT?

Comment: did you gave it a try with `timeout` ? both the places .

Comment: @Rainysidewalks do you mean use "TIMEOUT" instead of MY_TIMEOUT as the env var name?  I am not sure what you mean by "both the places".

Comment: yes and let me know the result